# Using a routing table to disallow connections to a VPN but also stream

Tags: networking, routes, twitch

I've been trying to access some content which requires me to connect via a Japanese connection. I am using softether to connect as it supplies me with a list of VPNs to instantly connect to a Japanese network. I need to be able to run my connection via this Japanese connect but also livestream, I have found the ingest server (noted below).

This is the ingest server I am trying to exclude: rtmp://live-cdg.twitch.tv/app

Which gives me the IP address of: **185.42.204.93** when I ping it.

I have tried to add it to the routing table and it says "OK!" but when I live stream it still thinks i'm in japan which makes me think it doesn't think it's working.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please show me output of `tracert 185.42.204.93` and also `tracert` to some Janapnese resource you are connecting to?